# Change GPT partition file system type with parted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, gpt

When I created my GPT partitions using `parted`, I was using `ext2` file system type perviously:

```
$ parted /dev/sdc print | grep ^12 
12      961GB   1118GB  157GB   ext2               msftdata
```

Now I want to change it to `ext4` instead, so I use `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc12` to reformat the partition, but when I do a `parted /dev/sdc print` as above, it is still showing `ext2` as the file system type.

I did some reading and seems that the only way for `parted` to touch the file system type is the `mkpartfs` command, Ref: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/parted-command-examples/. Is that so? I really don't like to use the `mkpartfs` command to change my file system type because I don't want to recreate my partition again. That will mess up with my partition numbering (sdc12 will be named as sdc19, for e.g.). Is there any better ways?

**EDIT:**

Bumped into the same problem again, and found the answer here, again, to my very own question. So, logging why I thought it was necessary to change the partition file system type:

```
% mount $bootdev
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

% fsck  $bootdev
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
GptLive: clean, 21/1024000 files, 74309/4096000 blocks

% mount $bootdev
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I.e., I newly created a `/dev/sdb2` entry with type `auto` in the `/etc/fstab`. However, `mount` just can't mount it. However:

```
% mount $bootdev /mnt/GptLive

% mount | grep $bootdev
/dev/sdb2 on /mnt/GptLive type ext2 (rw)
```

I.e., when `mount $dev` doesn't work, `mount $dev /mnt/place` worked just fine.

I don't know why and can't explain the fix, but just logging the fact that this is why I was looking for the solution, and how I *"fixed"* it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GParted and `parted` programs give only very limited control over the partition table type code information. At best, *some* type codes get translated into "flags." That's what the `msftdata` flag is -- it denotes a Microsoft Basic Data partition (GUID EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7; see the [Wikipedia list of GPT type codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)). You can change some type codes by adjusting flags, but Linux ignores these codes, except for certain limited situations, so on a Linux-only system, you shouldn't need to muck with them. On a dual-boot system, though, you should *not* set a Linux partition with the Microsoft Basic Data type code; see [my page on this topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html) for details of why this is a bad idea.

The identification of the filesystem as being ext2 in `parted` is done by the program examining the data *within* the partition. If you've created a fresh ext4 filesystem in the partition, then `parted` *should* be identifying it correctly; but there may be a bug in `parted`'s identification. If so, I wouldn't worry about it. You might want to verify that the partition really does hold an ext4 filesystem by using `blkid` (as in `sudo blkid /dev/sdc12`) or by examining the technical details with `dumpe2fs` -- but the latter requires a fair amount of expertise to interpret. In fact, ext4fs is basically ext2fs with extra features, so telling the two apart can be a bit tricky.

Comment: That's more than comprehensive, thanks a million. Yes, in my system, Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy, `parted` was not able to identifying it correctly, but as pointed out, `blkid` can.